# Redirect to route gives page loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, webforms

I'm trying to redirect to another route, if a variable is null. How ever it gives redirect loop error.

The routes:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("activities", "activities/{category}", "~/Pages/showAllActivities.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("activitiesSubPage", "activities/{page}", "~/default.aspx");
```

Code on showAllActivities.aspx:

```
if (category != null)
{
    ..
}
else
    Response.RedirectToRoute("activitiesSubPage", new { page = "1"});
```

Both routes URL need to start with "activities".

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the category and page parameters in the route are both numbers, there is no way ASP.NET can discern, so, for example, `/activities/2` will be matched by the first route and processed...

If they are different, for example category is a string and page is a number, you have [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992978.aspx) for MapPageRoute where you can provide default values and contraint for the rule (for example for the `/activities/{page}` route to accept only numbers:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("activitiesSubPage", "activities/{page}", "~/default.aspx",
    new RouteValueDictionary() { { "page", 0 } },
    new RouteValueDictionary() { { "page", "[0-9]+" } });
);
routes.MapPageRoute("activities", "activities/{category}", "~/Pages/showAllActivities.aspx");
```

Bear in mind that this configuration will send the `/activites` route to `/activities/0`, being 0 the default. I have put the {page} route above so it gets evaluated first and anything that goes past gets intercepted by the next rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved the problem! The page is a string aswell, but since the categories allways will be the same I used them in the regex instead of the number check. "^((Category1)||(Category2)||(Category3))"

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that it does not know if he passes `category` or `page`.

What you can do is map it to something like `/activities/category/{id}` (category id/name) and `/activities/page/{id}` (page id). It does not make sense to put `/activities/{id}` because it's not activity id, but page number.

Comment: Well, I've hoped it was possible. The navigation links looks like this: /activities/2012 (category) --- /activities/calendar (page)
Is it because it passing through all the routes again, even though I specified which one it should use?

Answer (score 0):

Check the links :

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

[How do I redirect a route to another route in ASP.NET web forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876599/how-do-i-redirect-a-route-to-another-route-in-asp-net-web-forms)